How can I seamlessly change an App Registrations "Application ID URI" domain?
I have a teams app which includes tabs. The tabs point at Domain A to authenticate the user using "microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate" and "microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken()". The teams manifest.json contains this section which points to my app registration in Entra:

I want to move the domain which hosts my teams app authentication flow to Domain B. I can't do that and have authentication continue to work without updating the "Application ID URI" in the "Entra -> App Registration -> [App Name] -> Expose an API" section and making it match the Domain B.

If try to change the tab urls without updating the "Application ID URI" I get this error message in the browser console:

"App resource defined in manifest and iframe origin do not match."

However if I were to change the "Application ID URI" it would break authentication for all the existing users of the app using Domain A (since they would get the same error) until the manifest is submitted to Microsoft and is approved, this takes time and would make the app inaccessible during this time.
I have considered switching to a new app registration however this is not feasible since existing users have already granted permissions to the existing app registration. It does not seem possible to have multiple valid Application ID URI's as Entra only provides one textbox for this property.
How can I seamlessly switch to a new domain, or am I stuck with the original domain for all time?
There is a (semi) related SO post here App resource defined in manifest and iframe origin do not match which explains that the tab domain and the application ID URI domain must match.

Please verify the contents of webApplicationInfo section:
"webApplicationInfo": {
"id": "{AAD App client id}",
"resource": "api://{app domain}/{AAD App client id}"
}
Please make sure the domain in webApplicationInfo is same as your app's domain, otherwise Teams will return error.

Yes, that's what the linked post (correctly) says. The problem is that if I change that in the manifest I also have to change it in the app registration which will break authentication for existing users until Microsoft approves thew new manifest. This is a live application, I can't afford that sort of downtime. Can I change this domain WITHOUT introducing downtime?

This can be one way so that you don't get any error- deploy the updated version of your Teams app with the new domain alongside the existing version with the old domain. Allow users to choose whether to continue using the old version or switch to the new version with the updated domain.

Thanks Vabihav, this doesn't seem like a viable solution though. Teams doesn't give users an option roll back to an older version, brand new customers won't ever get the option to even install the older version, and (from experience) Microsoft would not approve the new manifest unless it has the updated url (which would force me to also update it in the App registration and break existing authentication).

Another feasible solution can be- set up the authentication flow on Domain B and secondary app registration with the “Application ID URI” set to Domain B. This would allow you to test the new domain without affecting current users and gradually direct new users to authenticate via Domain B while maintaining the existing users on Domain A. When ready to switch over completely, update the manifest.json to point to Domain B and inform the users before.
